# When do Lorentz transformations take straight field lines to straight field lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

If you look at elementary examples, it seems like a Lorentz transformation takes a field pattern with a lot of straight field lines to another field pattern with a lot of straight lines. Examples:

- an electromagnetic plane wave, boosted longitudinally
- a parallel-plate capacitor, boosted along any axis of symmetry
- the field of a point charge that moves inertially

At first when I thought about this, I convinced myself that certainly it must be true that Lorentz transformations take straight field lines to straight field lines, and I just needed to find a proof. As I thought about it some more, I started to doubt whether it was true, and then whether it was even a well-defined statement. In general, if I show you the two field patterns, it isn't even defined which field lines map to which ones. I suppose the right way to state the conjecture might be the following:

Conjecture: Given an event P, suppose that the electric (magnetic) field line through P is straight (for some finite length), and the magnetic (electric) field is zero in some neighborhood of P. Then under a Lorentz transformation, the electric (magnetic) field line through P is again straight.

Is this the best/most interesting way to state it? Would it be better to state it in differential form, e.g., as a statement about the curvature of the field line? Is it true? Is it only true if we add some conditions? Do you need some kind of additional regularity condition?

My initial thought was that since the Lorentz transformation operates linearly on both space and the field tensor, clearly this must be true. Actually I don't think this holds up at all under examination.

As an example of a textbook treatment of this kind of thing, see Purcell, Electricity and Magnetism (3rd ed.), section 5.6, which gives a full, grotty derivation in the case of a point charge.

Comment: Since the electric and magnetic fields transform into each other, both should be straight in one frame for them to be straight in other frames.

Comment: @md2perpe: Good point, although I think that's not strong enough, since the field of a line of charge transforms into a curvy magnetic field. I think maybe it's necessary for the other field to be zero.

Comment: I believe this is the very definition of conformal mapping.

Comment: I edited the question to try to address md2perpe's point. @InertialObserver: Maybe I'm confused, but I think it's different for two reasons. (1) A conformal map preserves angles, a linear one preserves lines. (2) We're not just transforming the points, we're transforming the field that lives there and talking about its integral curve.

Comment: Since it happens for a uniformly moving point charge, doesn’t it happen for an arbitrary charge and current distribution, by superposition?

Comment: @G.Smith: Interesting idea. I don't think you can generally construct an arbitrary EM field as a superposition of the type you're talking about. Seems like any field with radiation would be a counterexample. Maybe your idea works for electrostatics/magnetostatics?

Comment: But those field lines aren’t straight, are they? You’re trying to show that if they are straight in one frame, they are straight in all frames. I think the missing part in my argument is that the only system with straight field lines needs to be for non-accelerating charges.

Comment: @G.Smith. Fields with straight field lines do not superpose to fields with straight field lines. Just look at two point charges like [this](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses-images-archive-read-only/wp-content/uploads/sites/222/2016/02/20113019/Figure_19_05_06a.jpg).

Comment: @md2perpe Ah, of course. My superposition idea was completely wrong.

Comment: If the field lines are linear at every time and static so that their directions don't vary over time, then I think that they will be linear in every frame.

Comment: Saying that the field lines are straight is, I think, equivalent to saying that $(\vec{E} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{E} = \alpha \vec{E}$ for some $\alpha$.  (Or similarly for $\vec{B}$.)  Perhaps one could apply the Lorentz transformations to that statement.

Comment: $ (E ⋅B)$ is invariant.  So if space were filled with uniform E and B, perpendicular to each other in one frame, such that $ (E ⋅B) = 0$ in that frame, they would need to be perpendicular to each other in all other frames.  Translational invariance ensures that the transformed field directions will be the same everywhere, which means the field lines will be straight in all Lorentz frames.

Answer (score -1):

In a Lorentz transformation, $E'_\perp/E'_\parallel$ is a linear combination of
$E_\perp/E_\parallel$ and $B_\perp/E_\parallel$, each of which don't depend on ${\bf r}$ if they are straight lines.  Therefore $E'_\perp/E'_\parallel$ is also constant.